# How to make recorded sound louder if recorded sound is low?

Tags: android, audio, mp3, record

I record a sound in my app but the volume recorded sound is too low. It will be good if *I can record the sound louder* or *make it loud while playing*.

This is my recording code :

```
myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
myRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + musicName + ".mp3");
myRecorder.setAudioChannels(2);
myRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(320);
myRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(48000);
```

Comment: What type of recording are you making? One where the user hold the phone up against his/her ear or mouth and speaks, or one where you're your recording something that's a few meters away?

Comment: the first one ... this is a karaoke app ... and it is so important to have the sound of the user loud enough ... when i merge the recorded sound and the background music , nothing will be still heared of the vocal ... the user knows to be near enough but it doesn't make it ... i want just a simple way to make the recorded sound louder ... it doesn't matter to be on the file or just while playing the sound ... thank you for your attention .